# Excel Gets Stuck on Save Through Macro

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a very extensive program written in Excel VBA that works perfectly fine, except when it attempts to save. Occasionally, not necessarily every time, the macro will save the workbook (in this case, export to CSV), but be stuck with the window labeled 'Saving,' a status message claiming that it's saving my file and a progress bar that will not progress further. It also has a button labeled 'Cancel,' which, when pressed, will continue the macro since the file has already been saved.

Here is the subroutine that I'm using:

```
Sub exportTable()
Dim varIsOpen As Boolean
Dim varSaveLocation1 As String, varSaveLocation2 As String
varIsOpen = False

If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ControlSheet").Range("D2").Value = "" Then
    varSaveLocation1 = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\CSVREVIEW\"
    varSaveLocation2 = varSaveLocation1 & Year(Now) & Month(Now) & Day(Now) & Hour(Now) & Minute(Now)
Else
    varSaveLocation1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ControlSheet").Range("D2").Value
    If Right(varSaveLocation1, 1) <> "\" Then varSaveLocation1 = varSaveLocation1 & "\"
    varSaveLocation2 = varSaveLocation1 & Year(Now) & Month(Now) & Day(Now) & Hour(Now) & Minute(Now)
End If
    For counter = 1 To Workbooks.Count
        If Workbooks(counter).Name = "TableBook.xls" Then varIsOpen = True

        If varIsOpen = True Then Exit For
    Next

    If varIsOpen = False Then GoTo isClosed

Workbooks("TableBook").Activate

'On Error Resume Next
If Len(Dir(varSaveLocation1, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
   MkDir varSaveLocation1
End If
If Len(Dir(varSaveLocation2, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir varSaveLocation2
End If
'On Error GoTo 0

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("test").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs varSaveLocation2 + "\test", xlCSV

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("part").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs varSaveLocation2 + "\part", xlCSV

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("logFile").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs varSaveLocation2 + "\logFile", xlCSV

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("deltaLimits").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs varSaveLocation2 + "\deltaLimits", xlCSV

ActiveWorkbook.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

isClosed:
End Sub
```

It may also be worth noting that I am currently saving to a server, but can't really remember if it did this while testing it on a local directory.

How can I get it to not hang? What is the cause of this problem and/or the solution to it?

Comment: *can't really remember if it did this while testing it on a local directory.*  Well, why don't you test it using a local directory or desktop folder? Does it exhibit the same problems? If not, then it would seem there's an issue accessing the server.

Comment: Have you tried breaking to see what line it's getting stuck at?

Comment: @DavidZemens a few problems with that start with the fact that getting 59,000 lines takes 10 minutes, as well as the fact that the problem can't be reproduced predictably.

Comment: @jmdon the program is clearly getting stuck on the save command. More often than not, it appears to get stuck on the line `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs varSaveLocation2 + "\deltaLimits", xlCSV`, but once again, the problem can not be reproduced predictably. I just know that I intend to let this program run 24/7 and the requirement of a human interaction inhibits the program's abilities.

Comment: @jmdon Ok, it just happened again and the break happened on `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs varSaveLocation2 + "\test", xlCSV` so it's completely random

Comment: It sounds like it's getting stuck in an indefinite loop somewhere. what happens when you run step through each line after you break the code?

Comment: @jmdon it's not an indefinite loop. There's no loop here, and any other loop is accounted for with `DoEvents`. If I were to step through it, it would simply bring up the saving window and do the exact same thing. (Show either a completely full or completely empty status bar and complete the process when cancelled)

Comment: You could try saving to a local directory then moving the file to the server.  This would split the question into two: (1) is there a problem with Excel saving a CSV file and (2) is there a problem writing to the server.

Comment: @TonyDallimore I left the program running at work saving to a local directory, so when I get back Monday I'll check it again. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the problem was actually just that it was saving to a server location. Saving locally ran the program flawlessly.

Thank you @TonyDallimore for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I had this start happening to my sheet - a pair of doevents around the .saveas fixed this for me.  I don't know why this is needed, or why it works, I saw it on a post (which I now cannot find).